# Selenium Xpath I am trying to select the checkbox in col2 where name is in col1 - using following axis or descendant

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML table with some rows and columns.
There is a row in the table with the text **"CRM" in column 1** and the **checkbox   in column 2**. 
I would like to select the **Checkbox** from this row and the **Checkbox is in column 2**.

I would like to **select the checkbox where column 1 has text "CRM"**

I would like to construct the Xpath, I think I can use the following axis or descendant axis to get to the checkbox having found the text "CRM" from column 1

I need some help to build the Xpath.
This is what I have tried so far:

This Xpath will find all of the checkboxes in column 2:

```
`//table[@class="myflextable"]//tr//td[text()="CRM"]/following::tr/td[2]//input`
```

This XPath will find the cell which has the text "CRM" in column 1.  This is a good start as i want to start from text "CRM"

```
//table[@class="myflextable"]//tr//td[text()="CRM"]
```

How do i go to the next column where the checkbox is?

The HTML is:

```
<table class="myflextable">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="myflextableheader">
    <tr>
        <td>
<span class="gwt-CheckBox">
<input id="gwt-uid-1377" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
<label for="gwt-uid-1377"/>
</span>
        </td>
        <td>CRM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<span class="gwt-CheckBox">
<input id="gwt-uid-1378" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
<label for="gwt-uid-1378"/>
</span>
        </td>
        <td>ESCR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<span class="gwt-CheckBox">
<input id="gwt-uid-1379" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
<label for="gwt-uid-1379"/>
</span>
        </td>
        <td>ORCHARD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
<span class="gwt-CheckBox">
<input id="gwt-uid-1380" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
<label for="gwt-uid-1380"/>
</span>
        </td>
        <td>Edit_test</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Do you want the checkbox where the id is `gwt-uid-1378`, `"//table//td[text()='CRM']/following::input[1]"`?

Comment: Yes or id 1377.  The ID is dynamic so i cannot use [@id="1377"] I would like to search by text

Comment: Then the code above will work, did you try it?

Comment: Yes just tried now.  It works.  Thanks!

Comment: Put it as an answer and i can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first following input after the td that contains the text you want.

```
//table//td[text()='CRM']/following::input[1]
```

Or also using the table class name:

```
 //table[@class='myflextable']//td[text()='CRM']/following::input[1]
```